# Botón no guarda ruta del archivo

Tags: python, tkinter

Defino una función para abrir la ruta de un archivo y cuando el botón hace la función y mando a llamar/imprimir la ruta del archivo no la guarda.

```py
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

ventana = Tk()

ventana.title("FLECHAS")

ventana.geometry("300x300")

ventana.configure(background='gray')


archivo=str()

def seleccionar_archivo():  # Función para seleccionar archivo .CSV del ordenador
    
    global archivo
    
    archivo = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",title="Seleccione archivo", filetypes=(("CSV", "*.csv"), ("Texto", "*.txt"),("all files", "*.*")))
    
    return archivo

Button(text="Abrir archivo", bg="yellow",command = seleccionar_archivo).place(x=50,y=50)

print(archivo)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Buen día, por favor edita tu pregunta y pon la descripción del problema en la publicación y un titulo que resuma el problema

Comment: Cuando haces `print(archivo)` es antes incluso de entrar en el bucle de eventos. En ese momento `archivo` no tiene valor asignado (bueno, sí, tiene una cadena vacía). El valor que quieres ver se asignará más adelante, cuando el usuario pulse el botón. Será entonces cuando se ejecute `seleccionar_archivo()` y se le asigne un valor. Por tanto tu `print(archivo)` debería estar dentro de esa función.

Comment: Ok. Pero el objetivo es que pueda seguir usando "archivo" fuera de la función, y cuando lo mando a llamar para hacer otras cosas no tiene ningun valor.

Comment: Porque seguramente lo mandas a llamar cuando _todavía_ no tiene ningún valor. Ten en cuenta que hasta que no se pulse el botón, su valor no cambia. Sería necesario ver el resto del código para mostrarte dónde lo haces mal y cómo arreglarlo